# String field aggregation from numerous lines to unique line

Tags: sql, list, hive, group-by, hiveql

For example, I could have this table :

[image]

I would like, with HQL, group my ID and aggregate my data. The result could be :
[image]

There is an operator like count or avg to aggregate strings like that ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441657/group-varying-number-of-rows-as-columns-in-hive-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collect_list()` to aggregate strings into array + `concat_ws(delimiter, array<string>)` for concatenating array to get delimited string:

```
select id, 
       concat_ws(' ',collect_list(data)) as aggregated_data
  from tbl
 group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collect_list`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-CollectionFunctions) to keep the duplicate data intact or use [`collect_set`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-CollectionFunctions) to remove duplicate values.

```
select id,collect_list(data)
from tbl
group by id
```